# How to subscribe to the DataTableFactory service?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to use [DataTablesBundle](https://omines.github.io/datatables-bundle/) in Symfony 4.2.

There is very good manual and starter however it is used with extends Controller class. But I am trying to use it with AbstractController
class.

So I have such issue:

> Service "`Omines\DataTablesBundle\DataTableFactory`" not found: even
>   though it exists in the app's container, the container inside
>   "`App\Controller\StaffController`" is a smaller service locator that
>   only knows about the "`doctrine`", "`form.factory`", "`http_kernel`",
>   "`parameter_bag`", "`request_stack`", "`router`",
>   "`security.authorization_checker`", "`security.csrf.token_manager`",
>   "`security.token_storage`", "`serializer`", "`session`" and "`twig`" services.
>   Try using dependency injection instead

I have found a solution however I have just started with Symfony so I haven't really understood what it is about:

https://github.com/omines/datatables-bundle/commit/cd9b93eac9ef4fd3c1459305c71ca6e2ac0c444e

> If using `AbstractController` instead,  which is currently
>   recommended practice, ensure you subscribe to the
>   `DataTableFactory` service yourself.  Alternatively you can
>   bypass the convenience trait and inject the service via regular
>   constructor injection

**How to subscribe to the DataTableFactory service?**

And what does the alternative "bypass the convenience trait and inject the  service" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to subscribe to a service, but here is how to inject it.

Add a constructor to your controller and inject the DataTableFactory:

```
//use Omines\DataTablesBundle\DataTableFactory;

private $factory;

public function __construct(
    DataTableFactory $factory
) {
    $this->factory = $factory;
}

/**
 * Creates and returns a basic DataTable instance.
 *
 * @param array $options Options to be passed
 * @return DataTable
 */
protected function createDataTable(array $options = [])
{
    return $this->factory->create($options);
}

/**
 * Creates and returns a DataTable based upon a registered DataTableType or an FQCN.
 *
 * @param string $type FQCN or service name
 * @param array $typeOptions Type-specific options to be considered
 * @param array $options Options to be passed
 * @return DataTable
 */
protected function createDataTableFromType($type, array $typeOptions = [], array $options = [])
{
    return $this->factory->createFromType($type, $typeOptions, $options);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$this->createDateTable();
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. Unfortunatelly this solution didn't work for me. I have had an error message: Attempted to call an undefined method named "createDataTable" of class "Omines\DataTablesBundle\DataTableFactory".

Comment: DataTableFactory doesn't have that function. There are only create() and createFromType() https://github.com/omines/datatables-bundle/blob/master/src/DataTableFactory.php

Comment: Maybe you need to inject another class? I don't use the bundle so I don't know.

Comment: It is inside of this trait: https://github.com/omines/datatables-bundle/blob/master/src/Controller/DataTablesTrait.php

Comment: Aha. I see I can to put it directly in a class. Thank you very much for your support. You have helped me a lot. It works now. I wish you a lot of success in all of your projects and plans!